# MVC 3 and strongly-typed views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been having multiple problems with getting the Add View.. “Create a strongly-typed view” dialog box option to work properly.

Most of the time, I am unable to get the Model classes to show up in the “Model Class” drop down.  This last issue is with Entity Framework classes that have been generated within the Model folder (and namespace).  I Rebuild the project and they still fail to show up.

In fact, if I add a test class to the Model folder with a few public properties—it is not showing up in the drop down.

Is their any information available on how this drop down pulls the Model classes to display to the end-user?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally rebuilding the project should be enough to show your custom class. But unfortunately this is far from perfect. Happens to me also. What I do is that I create my view model (not entity framework model because you should be passing only view models to your views), copy the name into the clipboard and paste it in the Add View dialog. I find this faster than scrolling through a dropdown of 1000 classes and finding the correct one.

Comment: I totally agree. I never use create view dialog to create the new view. I just drag the existing view, hold ctrl key and drop in view folder for copying view. And then I just rename and adjust model name for the new view.

Comment: Unfortunately pasting the name in (if not found in the list) then disables all the scaffolding functionality. It sets the scaffold template to empty. This just happened to me and closing and re-opening VS2010 fixed it. It seems to cache the list sometimes and not pick up changes from a rebuild.